# Ubuntu 18.10 - wrong desktop icons

Tags: 18.10

I just installed Ubuntu 18.10 on a laptop that had gnome 3.30, I formatted my `/` partition but kept my `/home/`. Now I see all my user home folders on the desktop instead of the correct desktop files. Is there a file to edit to correct this?

Comment: See the answer. Next time it would be better to rename your old account, so a fresh one is created on install. You can then easily move your own data over, and leave the inappropriate configuration data of your previous install behind.

Answer (score 1):

see `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

default values are like

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

You can restore them if the values are incorrect.